# URL Category rewrites not updated after the change

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, magento2.4

I'm using Magento 2.4.2, when changing the categories URL keys in the admin panel the URL rewrite sometimes isn't updated.

Why would it happen and how can I update them?

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple reasons for the same problem. But anyway, you might solve it by installing [olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites](https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites) and running these commands below.

```
php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=category
php bin/magento index:reindex
```

**Note: Before performing this please backup your database and commit your current code.**

Comment: Can I do that without installing a plugin? Sometimes it works...